# GCPにおいて1人のユーザーが複数のアカウントを使用について

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCPにおいて1人のユーザーが複数のアカウントを使用することが、利用規約に反する可能性はありますでしょうか？
ご存知の方がいれば、教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: 一般的には「1人1アカウント」で十分かと思うので、なぜ複数アカウントが必要な場合があるのかを説明した方が回答も付きやすいと思います。そうでなければ規約やヘルプを確認したり、Google に直接問い合わせるべき内容のように思います。

Comment: ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。

用途に関して、元々の個人GCPで作成したサーバがあり、そのサーバはそのまま維持したいと考えています（他の方には参照されない形で）。
追加で、チームでGCP上に新たなサーバを構築したいと考えています。
この際、新しいアカウントを作成すれば問題ないかと思い、このアイデアに至りました。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

通常、一般的なクラウドサービスの利用規約では、1つのアカウントを複数のユーザーが共有したり、1人のユーザーが複数のアカウントを作成して利用することが制限されていることがあります。これはセキュリティや請求の透明性などの理由から行われることがあります。

GCPでは、Googleの「一般的な利用規約」および「特定のサービスの利用規約」が適用されます。これらの規約は時折変更される可能性がありますので、最新の情報を確認することが重要です。

https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=ja

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
やはり、セキュリティや請求の透明性に欠ける点はありそうなので、今回は2個目のＧＣＰを作成するのはやめておきます。